# Error implementing firebase google json at android studio 3.1.2, Theme in style.xml is RED

Tags: android, json, build.gradle

I got an error in my Theme when I implement the firebaseand the plugin google json.

This is the build.gradle/module
[build.gradle/module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8JmY.jpg)
This is my build.gradle/project
[build.gradle/project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyM8c.png)
And I got this error at styles.xml
[stylesxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Ync.png)
Can anyone fix this Theme red error? ty


[error sync here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5wjd.png)

Comment: Can you try to use `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'` this library, let me know if it works.

Comment: i will put 15.0.2 in all firebase?

Comment: yes, if you have more firebase library, make sure all are same version.

Comment: gradle project sync failed,

Comment: can you provide the screenshot?

Comment: i edit the post. you can see there

Comment: Use `implementation` instead of  `compile`

Comment: i tried implementation and it synced, but the theme is still red

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all google support library uses the same version. Your first dependency `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` is in red means there is some version conflict. To see the error just place mouse courser on that red line and android studio will show you error in popup.

Comment: i posted a answer @jatin rana. i dont know how to upload picture at comment section. ty

Comment: @user9884237 Add this in module dependency
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'

Comment: @user9884237 To add more info edit the question or give screenshot link in comment section instead of answering it.

Comment: it work and the red is gone in implementation. ty. but the Theme in styles.xml still red. how can i fix that

Comment: Add this in module dependency api "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"

Comment: i put implementation or compile?

Comment: api or implementation beacuse compile is deprecated.

Comment: try implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0' instead of compile and  api 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'  
api 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 
api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
api "com.android.support:design:27.1.1

Comment: Are you facing any build issue or its just showing red? try clean project and then rebuild project from build menu.

Comment: on the red Theme says, Validate resource references inside Android XML Files.

Comment: i dont know the best build in android. my android sdk installed only android 8.1 and android 4.1

Comment: should i install all sdk tools?

Comment: Your compile sdk version is 27 , so yes it must be installed.

Comment: try sync project with gradle files from toolbar menu.

Comment: i tried sync with gradle then rebuild and clean. still red Theme. hmm.